# Identifying the basic operation of an algorithm

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

I am currently studying an algorithms unit at university and I can't seem to get a clear answer from anyone about determining the basic operation of an algorithm.  I understand it can occur in more than one place, but will it be different when considering best case, average case, and worst case?

In the following example, would I be correct in assuming A[i] = Null is the basic operation for best case, as it is the one that gives the best execution time?
And is A[i] = 0 the basic operation for worst case as it's code block will have the biggest execution time?
And how about average case?  Will it be all 4 comparisons with the array?
Like I said, I can't seem to get a clear answer from anyone.  Even the textbooks I've read are incredibly vague.  Any help will be very much appreciated.

```
for i <- 0 to n-1
    if A[i] = Null
       return
    else
       if A[i] < 0
          .....
          .....
          .....
       else if A[i] = 0
          for j <- 0 to n-1
             .....
             .....
             .....
       else if A[i] > 0
          .....
          .....
          .....
```

Comment: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/98577/how-do-i-determine-the-basic-operation-of-this-algorithm explains it.  The answer isn't very satisfying - choose what you want and just be sure to be consistent.

Comment: After reading the post, I can see why identifying the basic operation is so confusing.  It seems so arbitrary, so it's hard to know if there really is a "right" answer so to speak.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *O* notation is a function that *represents* the execution time a.k.a. time complexity. With increasing input size *n* a term will become the dominant term. The operation that is represented by this dominant term is what is called the basic operation.

Assuming all the dots in your example are *O(1)* these dots are your basic operation.

- In case `a[0] == null` the best case is *O(1)* (not really a case because it seems to represent missing data).
- In case `a[i] == 0` for each *i* the worst case complexity is *O(n^2)*.
- In case `a[i]` is a random value for each *i* the average case will be *O(n)* (although some values contain a zero and the average case might be a little above *O(n)*)

Answer (score 0):

The operation that dominates the performance of an algorithm is sometimes called the basic operation. In your example, it is the evaluation of A[i]. Depending on the outcome over n iterations, the algorithm performance will differ. How is often captured by specifying three corner cases - the best, the worst, and the average. Here it depends on how frequently A[i] evaluates to zero - never, always, or on average (assuming some distribution). The performance cases are often, but not necessarily, specified using big-O notation.

So the basic operation sets the performance, and the three performance cases indicate how it plays out.

Comment: Given the current example the evaluation of A[i] is either O(1) when A[i] == null or O(n) A[i] != null. There seems no evaluation of A[j] for A[i] == 0 if it was the term representing the evaluation would be in the same order as the execution of the assumed O(1) of the dots.

Comment: With evaluating A[i], I mean finding out whether A[i] is Null, <0, >0, or =0. Of these, Null is a stop criterion. Either A[i]=Null or i=n will terminate the algorithm. But in a Big-O analysis, the number of iterations N tends to infinity. So Null never happens, and i nor j never reaches n. In each iteration, if A[i] is non-0, an O(1) code sequence is run. If A[i] instead is 0, it is an O(N) sequence. So the full algorithm is somewhere between O(N) and O(N*N), depending on the size of the 0-fraction.